# Updating a query for false positives

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I work in a compliance role at a very small start-up and review a lot of information,for example bank transfers/direct deposits/ACHs every day. A report is pulled from BigQuery,which is exported to Google Sheets.

My question is there are a lot of false positives (basically, "posting data" that repeats often). I'm trying to eliminate it.

One idea, was just to update the query for key words:

`WHERE postingdata LIKE 'PersonName%'`

But it's tired and time-consuming. And I feel e there's a better way, perhaps 'filtering' the results and then feeding it back to the query. Any ideas or tips or just general thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can use [group by](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#group_by_clause) in your query. This is how you can use this clause.
You can see this code.

```
SELECT account,TypeTransaction,amount,currency
FROM `tblBankTransaction`
```

The code returns this data, and some rows are repeated; for example, rows 1 and 7 with the account `894526972455`, and it's a deposit.

[image]

In this case, I will use the group by clause.

```
SELECT account,TypeTransaction,amount,currency
FROM `tblBankTransaction`
group by account,TypeTransaction,amount,currency
```

And it returns this data:

[image]

You can see in this example that the account `894526972455` with a deposit only returns 1 row. The same account returns a second row, but is a transfer; it’s a different type of transaction. It depends on the information you have and what column you want to group.

Answer (score 0):

within GS you can try `UNIQUE` or `QUERY` with `group by` aggregation or `SORTN` with mode `2` as 3rd parameter